# Return 0 to second instance of duplicate

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a similar data set to the following:

```
A  B   C 
1  10  5 
1  20  1
2  30  1
2  30  1
```

I'd like to add a column returning 1, until we hit a duplicate of A & B, when I need to return a 0, but only for the second instance, so:

```
A  B   C  D
1  10  5  1
1  20  1  1
2  30  1  1
2  30  1  0
```

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

An option would be

```
df$D <- as.integer(!duplicated(df[c("A", "B")]))
df$D
#[1] 1 1 1 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a doodle with `library(dplyr)`:

```r
df %>% group_by(A,B) %>% mutate(D = +((1:n())==1))
```

Or if you want it to be zero *"only for the second instance"*, meaning the third instance would be also one, then the following works:

```r
df %>% group_by(A,B) %>% mutate(D = +!((1:n())==2))
```

In the example your duplicates are not for `A` and `B` only but also `C`. If that's actually the case, you can use `group_by_all` instead of `group_by(A,B)`.